# React list of components wrongly render on filter on li

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I have a react todo app where I can hide todos marked as done in the list. Todos marked as done have their title and description stiked thorugh.
[image]

The problem is when I hide done todos, the todo that takes its position in the list also have their text striked through along with the checkbox checked.
[image]

The code is as follows:

```
import TodoCard from "../components/TodoCard"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
import categories from "../data/todoCategory"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const VIEW_ALL_FILTER_VALUE = 9999;

export default function TodoList() {
    const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todo.todos)
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState(VIEW_ALL_FILTER_VALUE)
    const [filteredTodos, setFilteredTodos] = useState([])
    const [hideDone, setHideDone] = useState(false)


    useEffect(() => {
        let filtered = []
        if ((filter == VIEW_ALL_FILTER_VALUE)) {
            filtered = todos
        } else {
            filtered = todos.filter((item) => item.categories.includes(filter))
        }

        if (hideDone) {
            filtered = filtered.filter((item) => !item.isDone)
        }

        setFilteredTodos(filtered)

    }, [filter, hideDone, todos])

    return (
        <>
            <nav className="py-4 overflow-x-auto">
                <ul className="flex justify-start">
                    <li>
                        <button className={filter == VIEW_ALL_FILTER_VALUE ? "flex gap-1 mx-2 px-4 py-2 align-middle bg-gray-200 rounded" : "flex gap-1 px-4 py-2 align-middle rounded"} onClick={() => setFilter(VIEW_ALL_FILTER_VALUE)}>
                            <span>All</span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    {
                        categories.map((category, index) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={index}>
                                    <button className={filter == index ? "flex gap-1 px-4 py-2 align-middle bg-gray-200 rounded" : "flex gap-1 px-4 py-2 align-middle rounded"} onClick={() => setFilter(index)}>
                                        <div className={"w-6 h-6 rounded-full " + category.color}></div>
                                        <span>{category.label}</span>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div className="px-4 my-2">
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-400 bg-transparent border-2 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-2" checked={hideDone} onChange={() => setHideDone(!hideDone)} />
                    <label className="ml-1 text-sm">Hide Done</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="px-4 mt-4">
                <ul>
                    {
                        filteredTodos && filteredTodos.length > 0
                            ? filteredTodos.map((todo, key) => {
                                return (<TodoCard key={key} todo={todo} />)
                            }) : (
                                <div className="flex justify-center">
                                    <h5>No todos yet!</h5>
                                </div>
                            )
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import categories from "../data/todoCategory"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { removeTodo, toggleDone } from "../store/slice/todoSlice"

export default function TodoCard({ todo }) {
    const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsDone(todo.isDone)
    }, [])

    const toggleIsDone = () => {
        setIsDone(!isDone)
        dispatch(toggleDone({ id: todo.id }))
    }

    return (
        <li>
            <div className="p-4 my-4 bg-yellow-100 rounded-xl">
                <div className="flex items-start justify-between">
                    <div>
                        <h4 className={isDone ? "text-xl text-gray-800 line-clamp-2 line-through" : "text-xl text-gray-800 line-clamp-2"}>{todo.title}</h4>
                        <p className={isDone ? "mt-2 text-gray-600 line-clamp-2 line-through" : "mt-2 text-gray-600 line-clamp-2"}>{todo.description}</p>
                    </div>
                    <button className="w-4 h-4" onClick={() => {
                        dispatch(removeTodo({ id: todo.id }))

                    }}>
                        <svg className="text-red-600" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth={1.5} viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M14.74 9l-.346 9m-4.788 0L9.26 9m9.968-3.21c.342.052.682.107 1.022.166m-1.022-.165L18.16 19.673a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244 2.077H8.084a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244-2.077L4.772 5.79m14.456 0a48.108 48.108 0 00-3.478-.397m-12 .562c.34-.059.68-.114 1.022-.165m0 0a48.11 48.11 0 013.478-.397m7.5 0v-.916c0-1.18-.91-2.164-2.09-2.201a51.964 51.964 0 00-3.32 0c-1.18.037-2.09 1.022-2.09 2.201v.916m7.5 0a48.667 48.667 0 00-7.5 0" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <div className="flex justify-start gap-2 my-2">
                        {
                            todo.categories.map((category, key) => {
                                const color = categories[parseInt(category)].color
                                return (
                                    <div key={key} className={"w-6 h-6 rounded-full " + color}></div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-400 bg-transparent border-2 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-300 focus:ring-2" checked={isDone} onChange={toggleIsDone} />
                        <label className="ml-1 text-sm">Done</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}
```

```
import { createSlice, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const todoSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'todo',
    initialState: {
        todos: []
    },
    reducers: {
        addTodo: {
            reducer: (state, action) => {
                state.todos.unshift(action.payload)
            },
            prepare: (todo) => {
                const id = nanoid()
                return {
                    payload: {
                        id,
                        ...todo
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        removeTodo: (state, action) => {
            state.todos = state.todos.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id)
        },
        toggleDone: (state, action) => {
            state.todos = state.todos.map((item) => {
                if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
                    item.isDone = !item.isDone
                }
                return item
            })
        },
    }
})

export const { addTodo, removeTodo, toggleDone } = todoSlice.actions

export default todoSlice.reducer
```

I have tried passing the todo id to the TodoCard component instead of the whole todo object and read from the store but so far the behaviour stays the same

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Simple; don't use `index` as a `key`